# DataAnnotations attribute for float.NaN

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, data-annotations

I am using `DataAnnotations` for validation of my `ViewModel` `(WPF)` so I can control the enable state of some buttons if the user type in a something that is not a float and if the value is outside of a range.

```
    [Range(0, float.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "StepSize must be more than 0")]
            public float StepSize
            {
                get { return model.StepSize; }
                set
                {                   
                    model.StepSize = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedAndRevalidate(nameof(StepSize));
                }
            }

private void RaisePropertyChangedAndRevalidate(string propertyName)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (_fieldBindingErrors == 0)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
            }
        }


        private int _fieldBindingErrors = 0;
        public ICommand RegisterFieldBindingErrors
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand<ValidationErrorEventArgs>(e =>
                {
                    if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
                    {
                        _fieldBindingErrors++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _fieldBindingErrors--;
                    }
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
                });
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this,
                                   new ValidationContext(this, null, null),
                                   new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>())
                                   && _fieldBindingErrors == 0;

                return valid;
            }
        }
```

Problem is, when I convert the the textbox.Text string to a float I have to set the value to something not valid (should work for general cases also when the Range attribute is not in use). So I set the value to float.NaN.
The problem is that NaN seems to be a valid float, and it even passes the Range validation above.

Is there an attribute I could use to validate that the value is not NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, I created a custom validation rule instead and applied it in the XAML.

> class StepSizeValidationRule : ValidationRule
>      {
>           private int _min;
>           private int _max;
>
> ```
>     public StepSizeValidationRule()
>     {
>     }
>
>     public int Min
>     {
>         get { return _min; }
>         set { _min = value; }
>     }
>
>     public int Max
>     {
>         get { return _max; }
>         set { _max = value; }
>     }
>
>     public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
>     {
>         float stepSize = 0;
>
>         try
>         {
>             if (!float.TryParse(value.ToString(), out stepSize))
>             {
>                 return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a float");
>             }
>
>         }
>         catch (Exception e)
>         {
>             return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a float " + e.Message);
>         }
>
>         if (float.IsNaN(stepSize))
>         {
>             return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a float ");
>         }
>
>         if ((stepSize < Min) || (stepSize > Max))
>         {
>             return new ValidationResult(false,
>               "Please enter a stepSize in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return new ValidationResult(true, null);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```